# Avoid backtracking while creating loop in Google Map API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, direction

I am trying to build a solution where i would create loop by google map. My first and only business rule is there should not be any repeated route. But with my demo http://www.mindcrew.in/road%20runner/example.html it does show.

Please help me on this .

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us a little bit more about what this app is trying to do?  My guess is that after you specify a location and a distance, it tries to find a closed circuit of the desired distance originating at that point and your concern is that the existing algorithm performs a lot of backtracking.  However, these are purely guesses and could be mistaken.

Comment: You are right it does perform lot of backtracks and i would like to get rid of it.

Comment: I got the solution its about taking 45 degree angle and then work around

Comment: How can I accept my own solution ?

Comment: Could you post your solution here by entering it in the 'Your Answer' section below? You hinted at a solution by it's not very clear. Thanks!